# Django return render template and Json response

Tags: python, json, ajax, django, render

How could i render template in **Django** and as well make a **JsonResponse** in one return?

```
return render(request, 'exam_partial_comment.html', {'comments': comments, 'exam_id': exam})
```

Im trying to compine this with `JsonResponse` or something like this so it would render **exam_partial_comment.html** and also return

```
JsonResponse({"message": message})
```

so I could display message with ajax success funtction:

```
console.log(data.message)
```

Comment: You do realize that each response from the server has a certain content-type, right? What do you wany to return? JSON or HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as mentioned by @nik_m. You cannot send both html and json in your response. Plus, given the fact, Ajax calls cant render templates. Though, you can do something like this to achieve what you want

In views.py

```
def view_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        html = '<div>Hello World</div>'
        return JsonResponse({"data": html, "message": "your message"})
```

In html

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/view/',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
             console.log(response.message);
             $('#test').append(response.data);
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps.